# Multiclass linear SVM in python that return probability

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

How can I implement a linear SVM for multi-class which returns the proabability matrix for the test samples.
 Train samples: mxn
 Train labels: mxc
 Test labels : mxc, where column has the probability of each class.

The function in sklearn which does "one-vs-the-rest" [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) doesn't return probablity array for each sample like [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) which has `predict_proba`

**Edit**

Code:

```
        print X_train.shape,y.shape
        svc = LinearSVC()
        clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(svc, cv=10)
        clf.fit(X_train, y)
```

Output:

```
(7112L, 32L) (7112L, 6L)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SVC_Calibirated_Probability.py", line 171, in <module>
    clf.fit(X_train, y)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\calibration.py", line 110, in fit
    force_all_finite=False)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 449, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 485, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (7112L, 6L)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinearSVC` does not support probability estimates because it is based on `liblinear` but `liblinear` supports probability estimates for logistic regression only.

If you just need confidence scores, but these do not have to be probabilities, you can use `decision_function` instead.

If it it not required to choose penalties and loss functions of linear SVM, you can also use `SVC` by setting kernel to be `'linear'`, then you can have `predict_proba`.

#### Update #1:

You can use `SVC` with `OneVsRestClassifier` to support one-vs-rest scheme, for example

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, class_weight='auto'))
clf.fit(X, y)
proba = clf.predict_proba(X)
```

#### Update #2:

There is another way to estimate probabilities with `LinearSVC` as classifier.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target
svc = LinearSVC()
clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(svc, cv=10)
clf.fit(X, Y)
proba = clf.predict_proba(X)
```

However for the other question ([Making SVM run faster in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681373/making-svm-run-faster-in-python)), this solution is not likely to enhance performance either as it involves additional cross-validation and does not support parallelization.

#### Update #3:

For the second solution, because `LinearSVC` does not support multilabel classification, so you have to wrap it in `OneVsRestClassifier`, here is an example:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification

X, Y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=2, n_labels=1,
                                      allow_unlabeled=True,
                                      return_indicator=True,
                                      random_state=1)
clf0 = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(), cv=10)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(clf0)
clf.fit(X, Y)
proba = clf.predict_proba(X)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is possible to implement one vs rest in SVC?

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfect. I am implementing this on train-set with dimensions(1422392,29) and test-set (233081,29). It works very slow. Any suggestions? Can I parallelise, I couldn't find any examples online.

Comment: You can parallelize `OneVsRestClassifier ` by setting `n_jobs`. See the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) for more details.

Comment: Anyway to run the calibration faster, please explain. Without parallelization it will be extremely slow.

Comment: @yangje Thanks so much for your answer! Can you please explain if it works with binary labels, I tried it it gives an error.

Comment: Hi, I am talking about the second one here. Please my edit in the question it provides more details.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. It does not support multilabel becuause `LinearSVC` does not. You can wrap it with `OneVsRestClassifier` for multilabel, but you cannot expect high speed either.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can you please explain what do mean by "wrap" with it. Sorry, I am fairly new to ML and python terminology.

Comment: Just like the first solution, pass a `LinearSVC` estimator as the parameter of `OneVsRestClassifier`

Comment: Can you please change code if possible to make more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to do this but by doing the `CalibratedClassifierCV` of the `OneVsRestClassifier` instead of the other way around, and I was getting 
`ValueError: bad input shape (7769, 90)`