# How to use RandomForestClassifier for optimal results?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, scikit-learn, svm

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681373/making-svm-run-faster-in-python) question about improving SVM speed. The `RandomForestClassifier` works amazingly fast (~140 seconds on dataset of 50000 32X32 RGB images. *Just to compare, with regular SVC it took me ~140 for 2500 !! images*).

The problem with it is, that it has sub-optimal accuracy (<40% where the regular SVM with much less samples gave 50%). Is it possible to use it with linear / polynomial kernel like the regular `SVC(C = 0.01, kernel='poly', degree = 3)`)?

Comment: Is it worth asking this at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: SVMs work best with normalized data. Is your data normalized/ standardized?

Comment: Hmm... I don't really know what to answer. My data is decriptors (using sift) of images taken from cifar10 challange. Does that count as random?

Comment: First, try increasing `n_estimators` (default is 10 I think) and see if it improves cross validation accuracy (more estimators will slow down training however). Second, try playing around with `max_features`.