# I am trying to use an SVM model for machine learning, but it doesn't complete

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to use an SVM model on a dataset. It has 125973 records in the train and 22544 records in the test. It keeps computing forever and never completes. Can anyone help me. Below is my python code so far..

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.svm as s
import sklearn.metrics as m
import sklearn.preprocessing as pp

traindata = pd.read_csv("E:\\a-train.csv")

testdata = pd.read_csv("E:\\a-test.csv")

for col in traindata.columns:
    if traindata[col].dtype == type(object):
        le = pp.LabelEncoder()
        traindata[col] = le.fit_transform(traindata[col])
        
for col in testdata.columns:
    if testdata[col].dtype == type(object):
        le = pp.LabelEncoder()
        testdata[col] = le.fit_transform(testdata[col])

countS = 0

featsTrain = traindata.values[:,0:13]

featsTest = testdata.values[:,0:13]

lblsTrain = traindata.values[:,13]

lblsTest = testdata.values[:,13]

modelS = s.SVC(cache_size = 7000)

modelS.fit(featsTrain, lblsTrain)

lblsPredS = modelS.predict(featsTest)

for a,b in zip(lblsTest, lblsPredS):
   if a == b:
      countS += 1

accS = (round(countS/(len(featsTest)), 3)) * 100

print( m.confusion_matrix(lblsTest, lblsPredS) )

print(m.classification_report(lblsTest, lblsPredS))

print("\nAccuracy = ", accS, "%")
```

Comment: what is the configuration of the server that you are using? this post might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940258/svc-classifier-taking-too-much-time-for-training/54004026

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this post, this might solve your issue/use case:

[SVC classifier taking too much time for training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940258/svc-classifier-taking-too-much-time-for-training/54004026)