# Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation taking too long

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, rfe

The recursive feature elimination with cross-validation is taking too long to run. How do I increase the speed?

X and y

```
X = df.iloc[:,7:-2]  
y = df["subtype"]
```

`X.shape`

```
(867, 142513)
```

Scale the dataset

```
# scale the dataset
sc = StandardScaler()
X = pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(X))
```

RFE with cross-validation

```
# Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation
## Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
## The "accuracy" scoring shows the proportion of correct classifications

min_features_to_select = 7000  # Minimum number of features to consider
rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=svc,
    step=7,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(5),
    scoring="accuracy",
    min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select,
)
rfecv.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Comment: This is likely just because you're fitting many `SVC`s to fairly large datasets: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53940258/10495893

Comment: Should I perform dimensionality reduction prior to scaling?

Comment: I mentally interchanged the number of rows and columns; I'm not sure how well SVC scales to a huge number of columns, and my linked Q discusses many rows.  How long does a single SVC fit on your full dataset take? // RFE _is_ a dimensionality reduction, although maybe something "cheaper" would be a good start.  Consider also `linearSVC` instead of `SVC(kernel='linear')`.