# What is the correct way to calibrate probabilities when you have multiclass problem?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, grid-search, calibration

I am training a model to predict the label (target) based on loan status e.g. 0,1,2,3. So i have 4 classes. I have so far trained a model as follows:

```
  from HyperclassifierSearch import HyperclassifierSearch

X = data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = data.label

    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=42)
# Create a hold out dataset to train the calibrated model to prevent overfitting
X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, 
stratify=y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
              
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, fill_value=0) ),('scaler', StandardScaler())])
   
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),
                                    ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_cols)])


#then i use hyperclassifer library 

models = {  'xgb': Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('clf', XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob'))]),
                       'rf': Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('clf', RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 42))]) }


search = HyperclassifierSearch(models, params)
best_grid = search.train_model(X_train, y_train, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy')
results = search.evaluate_model()
fitted_model = best_grid.best_estimator_

pred = fitted_model.predict_proba(X_test)
labels = fitted_model.predict(X_test)
```

**note i have omitted alot of the imported libs and params dict since large and only included hyperclassifier since it is large **

my pred is a matrix containing 4 columns where each is related to the class of the loan. Generally i know it is good pracitce to calibrate the probabilities and particularly from tree based algorithms the output is a score not really a probability. I am however confused as to how to calibrate these probabilities.

###### Usually i would calibrate using the holdout validation set but am unsure how to do it with multiclass

## Update

Should i ammend the above xgbclassifier by doing the following:

```
OneVsRestClassifier(CalibratedClassifierCV(XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob'), cv=10))
```

source: [Multiclass linear SVM in python that return probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617530/multiclass-linear-svm-in-python-that-return-probability)

###### My question is what is the correct way to calibrate probabilities from multiclass model?

Comment: "the correct way" seems to me to be a statistical question, which would belong better over at stats.SE or datascience.SE

Comment: will move to cross validated

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/543897/how-to-calibrate-with-multiclass-classification-problem